NestJS: Exception filter prisma not called when defined globally
I have a prisma filter that I found online. When declaring it as a global filter in the entry function of nest, it isn't applied to my routes by default.
To declare it I was using app.useGlobalFilters(new PrismaClientExceptionFilter())
Though, when setting on my controller it works fine.
@Controller('upcoming-sales')
@UseFilters(PrismaExceptionFilter)
export class UpcomingSaleController {

I thought declaring it as a global filter would work. I don't understand where do I get my setup wrong.
If you need to see my main file for configuring NestJS I can provide it.
